# Compose BottomSheetScaffold with sheet top margin

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, bottom-sheet

I was playing around with `BottomSheetScaffold` and could't figure out how to set a top margin / min offset / anchor for the sheet.

Setting up the sheet like this:

```
val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()
BottomSheetScaffold(
    sheetContent = {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            items(100) {
                Text(text = "Sheet item $it")
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            }
        }
    },
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    sheetPeekHeight = 100.dp,
    sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
    sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Gray
) { innerPadding ->
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(innerPadding)
            .background(Color.Green),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) { Text(text = "Content") }
}
```

Results in this bottom sheet in the app:

Collapsed:

[image]

Expanded:

[image]

What I am looking for is to add a top margin for the sheet so that it doesn't expand more than to this state.

[image]

I know I could add a height to the sheet content, but then i had to calculate `height = windowHeight - bottomNavHeight - sheetTopMargin` and that just feels more complicated that it should be.

Is there any easier way to set the top sheet margin?

Comment: It's not ideal but if you put the scaffold inside a container, the bottom sheet will only expand to the height of the container.

Answer (score 10):

We used a **ModalBottomSheetLayout** and provided the maximum height as a factor of screen space to the `modifier` of the `sheetContent` composable:

```kotlin
sheetContent = {
    DatesFilterSheet(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(0.9f)
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

As mentioned [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/209825720#comment1) there is no easy way to do this for now.
However the `Modifier.onGloballyPositioned` workaround seems to be working fine for me.

The way it goes is:

1. We will first calculate the `screenHeight` height and `topAppBarHeight` using the `Modifier.onGloballyPositioned`
2. After that we need to calculate `lazyColumnHeight` which will be:
   `lazyColumnHeight` = `screenHeight` - `topAppBarHeight`
3. Now this `lazyColumnHeight` needs to be put to `LazyColumn(Modifier.requireHeight(lazyColumnHeight)...){...}` So that `LazyColumn` will only consume this fixed max height.

## Steps detail and code

### step 1:

Calculate `screenHeight` and `topAppBarHeight`

```
    var screenHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
    var topAppBarHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
    val localDensity = LocalDensity.current

    BottomSheetScaffold(modifier = Modifier
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            with(localDensity) { screenHeight = it.size.height.toDp() }
        },
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(modifier = Modifier
                .onGloballyPositioned {
                    with(localDensity) { topAppBarHeight = it.size.height.toDp() }
                }

            ) {...}
        }
    )
```

### Step 2 and 3:

Now that we have got `screenHeight` and `topAppBarHeight`. We will  put the difference of these two as it to `LazyColumn`'s height:

```
var screenHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
var topAppBarHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
val localDensity = LocalDensity.current

BottomSheetScaffold(modifier = Modifier
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            with(localDensity) { screenHeight = it.size.height.toDp() }
        }
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(modifier = Modifier
                .onGloballyPositioned {
                    with(localDensity) { topAppBarHeight = it.size.height.toDp() }
                }
            ) {...}
        },
        sheetContent = {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .requiredHeight(screenHeight - topAppBarHeight)
            ) { ...}
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no easier way to do this, you could try to set a Column around your lazy column with a spacer before, which is only shown when the sheetState is Expanded. If you leave it when it's collapsed then there is a white gap at the bottom.

In addition you need to set the sheetBackgroundColor to Transparent and use Color.grey on your LazyColumn

Comment: Yes, sounds like this could work as well. Although not as well when you manually slide the bottom sheet up and down. I really hope they are going to add support for this some time soon

Comment: I think this should be possible to, you just have to listen to state changes but then it will probably be a bit buggy because it's to slow realizing it but in the end I think your solution is easier to implement :) Yes looking forward to updates on support for this!